Connecting an IC Power Pin to the Power Plane via Vias
In my design, I have a dedicated power plane. I’m wondering whether I should connect the power pin of the IC directly to the power plane polygon or use thermal relief.

Considering it is connected to the IC pin, I thought that if I do not use thermal relief, the pin may not be soldered well enough during the soldering process.


What purpose does your thermal relief fulfill?

Considering it is connected to the IC pin, I thought that if I do not use thermal relief, the pin may not be soldered well enough during the soldering process.

@Marcus Müller I edited the question as well

ah, are you going to hand-solder this, or is this goig to be reflow soldered?

@Marcus Müller this will be reflow soldered.

Your concern is generally valid – one avoids having capacitors (and resistors, and other 2-pad small components) with one pad on a metal plane without thermal reliefs for the reason that the solder on that side might melt slower, and then the other side's solder has already molten, and developed surface tension, and might pull away the capacitor, and turn it upright; so-called "tombstoning".
It's usually not a concern when there's a via between the metal plane and the pad, either: until enough heat has flown through the via, a reflow oven will usually have molten the solder enough for tombstoning not to occur.
That problem doesn't apply to your case with an IC, there's enough mass and other pins that will hold the IC into place long enough until all solder has molten.
SMD Reflow is much easier to get right for small components like these. You'll see plenty of thermal reliefs on through-hole and manually soldered components, but usually, an SMD reflow temperature profile is designed such that it reliably heats up the whole PCB, anyways (because you need to solder under ICs, for BGA and similar packages), so the problems that you have with a soldering iron, namely, that you just can't get a pad to become hot enough to accept solder, simply don't apply. The only thing going for thermal reliefs for SMD reflow work is that it can help to make the speed more uniform, and as explained above, that's only relevant for small, 2-pad components that can be pulled away by one side.

then as conclusion i can use direct connection right?

would you please also to vote on my question? thanks
